# Kotlin how to put extra from Activity to Service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, service

I think I now how to put extras, but don't know how to get them

```
Intent(this, MyService::class.java).also { intent ->
    bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    intent.putExtra("ip1", ip1)
    intent.putExtra("port1", port1)
 }
```

I tried with something like val ip1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("ip1") but it doesn't work, it also says getIntent() is deprecated and to use parseUri instead.

Comment: you should put extras before using intent with bindService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the intent parameters **before** binding to the service:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)
intent.putExtra("ip1", ip1)
intent.putExtra("port1", port1)
bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

And use the intent from the service's **onBind** method to get the values back:

```
override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    val ip1 = intent.getStringExtra("ip1")
    val port1 = intent.getStringExtra("port1")
    ...

    return binder
}
```